# operator inside operator not working

Tags: c++, operators

```
char b;

operator<<(cout,(operator>>(cin,b)));
```

this is not compiling in vc++ because all 8 overloads cant convert this type.

can any one explain this.....

is their a problem with return type...........

Comment: Please don't... but I just feel like it: `char b; cout << ((cin >> b), b)`

Comment: Note that using `operator<<(cout,b)` is not idiomatic. `cout << b` is semantically equivalent but much easier to write and read. @David: Oh hell!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stream extraction operation i.e. `op>>` returns an object of type `istream&`. The `op<<` does not have an overload which takes `istream&` as its second parameter. You need to split the two actions or define one such overload.

Answer (score 0):

```
char b;
operator<<(cout,(operator>>(cin,b),b));
```

Comment: Spookily near identical to the code in the comment by David Rodriguez, posted 18 minutes earlier.

Comment: Nice one. Another interpretation of OP's code: `cout.operator<<(operator>>(cin, b))`. That would print the address of cin, though (result of conversion to `void*`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the output operator that would work takes a `void*`, but that is a member. If you change it to the following, it will convert the `istream&` returned by the `operator>>` to `void*` and output it (and it is a null pointer if the extraction worked, and a non-NULL pointer otherwise):

```
cout.operator<<(operator>>(cin,b));
```

I'm not quite sure though why you are doing this. Can you please elaborate? If you want to output all stuff from `cin` right away, use the underlying buffer

```
cout << cin.rdbuf();
```